# Avoid Pushing between rigidbody

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, unity3d-2dtools

I have a issue with my 2D game in unity (pokemon style), I'm using `transform.position` to move the gameobjects.

I have a player and enemies that follow him, all is ok. But when the enemies make a collision, they begin to push each other

I need that nobody to be pushed when the enemies and player get a collision.

- I tried to use kinematic in enemies, but the player can push them.
- I tried to add a big amount of mass to the player, but he can push the enemies.
- I tried to detect the collision in code with `OnCollision`, but when I cancel the enemy movement, they don't return to move.

----UPDATE----

I need the collision but without pushing between them, here is a video to illustrate the problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkgnV1NOxlw

Just for the record, i'm using A* pathfinding script (http://arongranberg.com/astar/) here my enemies move script.

```
void FixedUpdate () {
    if(path == null)
        return;

    if(currentWayPoint >= path.vectorPath.Count)
        return;

    Vector3 wayPoint = path.vectorPath [currentWayPoint];
    wayPoint.z = transform.position.z;

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, wayPoint, Time.deltaTime * speed);

    float distance = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, wayPoint);

    if(distance == 0){
        currentWayPoint++;
    }

}
```

----UPDATE----

Finally I'll get the expected result,changing the rigidbody2D.isKinematic property to true when the target was close and stop it

Here is a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Zm0idUU75s

And the enemy movement code

```
void FixedUpdate () {

    if(path == null)
        return;

    if(currentWayPoint >= path.vectorPath.Count)
        return;

    float distanceTarget = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, target.position);

    if (distanceTarget <= 1.5f) {
        rigidbody2D.isKinematic = true;
        return;
    }else{
        rigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
    }

    Vector3 wayPoint = path.vectorPath [currentWayPoint];
    wayPoint.z = transform.position.z;

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, wayPoint, Time.deltaTime * speed);

    float distance = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, wayPoint);

    if(distance == 0){
        currentWayPoint++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've made? Please show us the code, and an image of the scene, if possible.

Comment: @Bobthezealot seems like he is looking for a method of avoiding collision.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in several ways,

You can use [`Physics2D.IgnoreCollision`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreCollision.html)

```
Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(someGameObject.collider2D, collider2D);
```

- Make sure that you do the `IgnoreCollision` call before the collision occurs, maybe when objects instantiate.

or alternatively you can use, `Layer Collision Matrix`

[image]

- [Unity Manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) provides information on using this. This simply does the collision avoidance by assigning different `GameObjects` to different layers. Try: 
   `Edit->Project Settings->Physics`

Or if you want it to just stop moving, You can easily do it like,

```
bool isCollided = false;

// when when OnCollisionEnter() is called stop moving. 
//maybe write your move script like 

void Move() { 
    if(!isCollided) { 
        // move logic 
    } 
}
```

Comment: thank for your answer, but im not trying to avoid collisions, i need collision but without pushing between objects  (look the question update)

Comment: @LuisCruz Not pushing means you want both objects to stop? or what?

Comment: Yes, i want that both objects to stop when they get a collision

Comment: why don't you just have a flag like `bool isCollided` and when when `OnCollisionEnter()` is called stop moving. maybe write your move script like `void Move() { if(!isCollided){ // move logic } }`

Comment: if i use a flag both enemies get stopped permanently, because they enter in collision and cancel the move in both enemies, I tried it and doesn't work

Comment: i'm out of ideas, Unity doesn't has a native way to prevent the push between 2 Rigidbody 2D?

Comment: I think it should be like this, 1. when two enemies collide, do the A* again (for one enemy) and do the move again. or 2. In 2d you can just dissable rigid boies and make them pass though and enable them after that

Comment: Yes, I think I need a complex way to check the collision and stop the pushing effect, maybe with Physics2D.OverlapCircle